# ValueError while in SVC

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

This is a cancer dataset with 10 features and a class.

```
 X=df.iloc[:,1:10].values
 y=df.iloc[:,[-1]].values
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
imputer=Imputer(missing_values='NaN',strategy='mean',axis=1)
imputer=imputer.fit(X)
X=imputer.transform(X)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=0)

from sklearn.svm import SVC
classifier=SVC (kernel='rbf',random_state=0)
classifier.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred=classifier.predict(y_test)
```

When I execute this I get

```
ValueError: X.shape[1] = 1 should be equal to 9, the number of features at training time
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error was caused by the following line, where you passed `y_test` instead of `X_test`:

```
classifier.predict(y_test)
```

Full code:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
from sklearn.svm import SVC


data = load_breast_cancer()
df = pd.DataFrame(data.data, columns=data.feature_names)

X=df.iloc[:,1:10]
y = data.target

imputer=Imputer(strategy='mean',axis=1)
X = imputer.fit_transform(X)

X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=0)

clf = SVC(kernel='rbf').fit(X_train, y_train)


y_pred=clf.predict(X_test)
print(clf.score(X_test, y_test))
```

yields:

```
0.6842105263157895
```

Comment: I predicted y_test instead of X_test.Use gamma=0.01,C=1 and you will get good accuracy.Tell me if u got

Comment: @Anesh, sorry, i don't get it. `y_test` - is your result (ground true) - it can't be used for predicting. It's used for checking (scoring)...

Comment: 'y_pred=clf.predict(y_test)' I used this instead X_test.Thats y it showed error.I got 96% with gamma-0.01 C:1 random_state=0

Comment: @Anesh, ah, I got you now. Yes, i didn't tune hyperparameters... We could use GridSearchCV for tuning...

Comment: Yesss.GridSearchCV is the best.